# Get coordinates of the keypoint from OpenCV matches of SIFT

Tags: c++, opencv, sift

I want get coordinates of the keypoint from OpenCV matches of SIFT, and I don't know the annotation of data structure of matches. I have been trying to do it like:

```
vector<DMatch> matches;
matcher.match(descriptors1,descriptors2,matches);
for(vector<DMatch>::size_type i=0; i<matches.size(); i++)
{
    cout<< key_points1[ matches[i].trainIdx].pt <<"与之匹配特征点坐标"<< key_points2[ matches[i].imgIdx].pt<<endl; 
}
```

But it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I've tried your method and it works just fine, how are you storing your keypoints? Some more code would be helpful if you're still stuck.

Comment: Could you please elaborate "_does not work_"? What kind of error message do you have?  Or describe the difference between the actual and the expected output.

Answer (score 3):

The *match* function of class *DescriptorMatcher* has the following signature:

```
void match( const Mat& queryDescriptors, const Mat& trainDescriptors,
            vector<DMatch>& matches, const Mat& mask=Mat() ) const;
```

I am assuming that **key_points1** correspond to **descriptors1** and **key_points2** to **descriptors2**.

The first thing to look into would be that you pass **descriptors1** as **queryDescriptors** but then use **trainIdx** as index. You would probably have to use **queryIdx** there.
Consequently, for **key_points2** you would have to use **trainIdx**.

```
vector<DMatch> matches;
matcher.match(descriptors1,descriptors2,matches);
for(vector<DMatch>::size_type i=0; i<matches.size(); i++)
{
  cout<< key_points1[ matches[i].queryIdx].pt // Query is first.
      <<"与之匹配特征点坐标"
      << key_points2[ matches[i].trainIdx].pt // Training is second.
      <<endl; 
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you.  I have got it.I use the same solution as you said